# What scopes / roles are required for a service account to be able to submit container builder jobs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When creating a new service account to handle Container Builder jobs, the jobs fail with the following error despite the service account having `Cloud Container Builder` , `Logs Viewer` and `Private Logs viewer`:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.builds.submit) HTTPError 403:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access denied.</Message>
  <Details>v2-container-builder@redacted.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to object redacted.cloudbuild-logs.googleusercontent.com/log-20117c17-f2b4-4159-9883-104ddd7bb232.txt.
  </Details>
</Error>
```

I understand the error points to `storage.objects.get` permissions over a file on cloud storage, but this is not a bucket we can set `acl` for is it ?

Answer (score 7):

Here is the quote from David Bendory (Tech Lead for the Google Cloud Container Builder) from [this thread](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/120):

> GCS permissions predate IAM and thus work a little differently. To
>   view the logs, the Service Account in question needs to be a Viewer on
>   the project in addition to have the Builder Editor role.

Comment: Also make sure that you own the role "Viewer" on the project level and not the role "Role Viewer".

Comment: Thank you @TobiasErnst, the last puzzle piece for me :)