# gcloud build. <service account> does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object

Tags: gcloud, service-accounts, google-cloud-run, google-iam

When I run this in cmd line:

```
gcloud builds submit --tag "gcr.io/<project id>/<cloudrun app name>"
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) HTTPError 403: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied.</Message><Details>[service accoun name]@[project-id].iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.</Details></Error>
```

Here are the roles I've assigned to the Service account (yes, its overkill, just trying to get it to work):

[image]

I've tried these solutions, but they haven't worked:

- [service account does not have storage.objects.get access for Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51410633/service-account-does-not-have-storage-objects-get-access-for-google-cloud-storag)
- [(gcloud.app.deploy) HTTPError 403: <account> does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65455295/gcloud-app-deploy-httperror-403-account-does-not-have-storage-objects-get-a)
- [What scopes / roles are required for a service account to be able to submit container builder jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45602447/what-scopes-roles-are-required-for-a-service-account-to-be-able-to-submit-cont)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you perform a `gcloud config list` and share the result?

Answer (score 4):

Hello I had the same issue. Solved it by adding the role "Viewer" to my service account as explained here : https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud/issues/105

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I can't find a role just called "Viewer". Can you please be more precise @bourliam ? What exact "Viewer" role did assign?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please confirm that you are using the default service account to trigger your build? If you are using a different service account to trigger the build, use the similar role which your default service account has as well.

Make sure you have the following roles for the service account:

1. Cloud Build Service account
2. Service Account User
3. Cloud Run Admin

You can change the permissions from the Cloud Build Settings [page](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-cloud-run#required_iam_permissions).

Then try running your builds again.

Comment: This didn't work. I created a new service account with the permissions you have described, still gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a new service with a **prebuilt demo container from the web console** like described [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/prebuilt-deploy)?

We got the same error ("... does not have storage.objects.get access ...") initially, but it worked once we created a first demo service using the Google Cloud Console.